# Automatic Update to SQL Server CE local database using sync framework

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I have deployed the sync framework for Oracle and SQL Server CE using the following link

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-Oracle-and-037fb083 successfully.

The SQL Server CE database updates after pressing synchronize button when I made any changes to the Oracle database.

But I need to update the SQL Server CE database (local cache database in my case) automatically once I made any change to the Oracle database, without pressing the synchronize button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can invoke the sync from code based on system events or a timer...

Comment: Thanks. But I am searching for builtin method or api inside the sync framework for doing this, Is there any builtIn feature for the change detection in the syncframework api, so that we can automatically fire the synchronization